# How can I have Image and Text for Picker in SegmentedPickerStyle in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, picker

I am building a Picker with SwiftUI.

Now i want do add an icon AND text for each selection. So it should look something like this:

[image]

Is this possible? If yes how to do it?

Or is it not recommended by Apples apples human interface guidelines at all?

I already tried to use a HStack to wrap image and text together.

```
enum Category: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case person
    case more

    var id: String { self.rawValue }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var category = Category.person

    var body: some View {
        Picker("Category", selection: $category) {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "person")
                Text("Person")
            }.tag(Category.person)
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
                Text("More")
            }.tag(Category.more)
        }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
        .padding()
    }
}
```

But the framework splits it up into four.

[image]

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot with what you have tried.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a trivial way of doing this. You shouldn't really mix images + text here anyway, it should be either but not both.

Comment: This seemed like a simple question: just put a `Label` instead of the `HStack`... 
But it does not work?! I have also tried to use a custom `LabelStyle`... but without success.
It seems as if the `SegmentedPickerStyle` only uses one of the two provided views. Choosing a `WheelPickerStyle` would show the label as expected. It's definitely an issue with the segmented picker only.

Comment: According to [Apple Human Interface Guidelines for segmented controls](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/segmented-controls/) it is definitely not desired to have both text and image. So it is not a bug of SwiftUI, but a feature: you cannot do it wrong :-)

Answer (score 7):

You can make a custom Picker

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    Home()
}
}

struct Home: View {

@State var index = 0
var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        HStack {
            Text("Picker with icon")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
            Spacer(minLength: 0)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        
        
        HStack(spacing: 0){
            HStack{
                Image(systemName: "person")
                    .foregroundColor(self.index == 0 ? .black : .gray)
                Text("Person")
                    .foregroundColor(self.index == 0 ? .black : .gray)
                
                
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 10)
            .padding(.horizontal, 35)
            .background((Color.white).opacity(self.index == 0 ? 1 : 0))
            .clipShape(Capsule())
            .onTapGesture {
                self.index = 0
            }
            
            HStack{
                Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
                    .foregroundColor(self.index == 1 ? .black : .gray)
                Text("More")
                    .foregroundColor(self.index == 1 ? .black : .gray)
                
                
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 10)
            .padding(.horizontal, 35)
            .background((Color.white).opacity(self.index == 1 ? 1 : 0))
            .clipShape(Capsule())
            .onTapGesture {
                self.index = 1
            }
        }
        .padding(3)
        .background(Color.black.opacity(0.06))
        .clipShape(Capsule())
        Spacer(minLength: 0)
    }
    .padding(.top)
}
```

}
[image: example]

Comment: Thank u very much! I spend a lot of time to find out how to do similar segmented controller, especially how to change height of segmented controller

Comment: Could you please say how you show view when selecting specific segment?

Comment: Embed in Zstack and add condition (if index == 0 {View1}else if index == 1 {View2}....)

Comment: @AdR can you please improve answer with more system looks like animations? And also with example of selecting as improve overall. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a way using Apple Picker with the output you want:

```
enum Category: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case person
    case more
    
    var id: String { self.rawValue }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var category = Category.person
    
    private var view1: some View { HStack { Image(systemName: "person"); Text("Person") } }
    private var view2: some View { HStack { Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle"); Text("More") } }
    
    @State private var uiImage1: UIImage? = nil
    @State private var uiImage2: UIImage? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        
        return Picker("Category", selection: $category) {
            
            if let unwrappedUIImage1 = uiImage1 {
                Image(uiImage: unwrappedUIImage1)
                    .tag(Category.person)
                
            }
            
            if let unwrappedUIImage2 = uiImage2 {
                Image(uiImage: unwrappedUIImage2)
                    .tag(Category.more)
                
            }
            
        }
        .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
        .padding()
        .onAppear() {
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                uiImage1 = viewToUIImageConverter(content: view1)
                uiImage2 = viewToUIImageConverter(content: view2)
            }
            
            print("Your selection is:", category.rawValue)
        }
        .onChange(of: category, perform: { newValue in print("Your selection is:", newValue.rawValue) })
        
    }
}



func viewToUIImageConverter<Content: View>(content: Content) -> UIImage? {
    
    let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: content)
    let view = controller.view
    
    let targetSize = controller.view.intrinsicContentSize
    
    view?.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize)
    view?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: targetSize)
    
    return renderer.image { _ in
        view?.drawHierarchy(in: controller.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: I tired the the code above, all the options are just in white, no icon or text shown. Any clue?

Comment: Just white for iOS 16

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possibility with a @ViewBuilder for building items. It's adaptable for your needs, hope it can help !

```
import SwiftUI

struct CustomPicker<T: Identifiable & Equatable, C: RandomAccessCollection<T>, Content: View>: View  {
    let items: C
    @Binding var selection: T
    @ViewBuilder let itemBuilder: (T) -> Content
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(items) { source in
                Button {
                    selection = source
                } label: {
                    itemBuilder(source)
                        .padding()
                        .background(selection == source ? Color.white : Color.clear)
                        .cornerRadius(7)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                }
                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                .animation(.default, value: selection)
            }
        }
        .padding(4)
        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.4))
        .cornerRadius(7)
        
    }
}

struct Item: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
}

struct CustomPicker_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    struct Container: View {
        @State var selection = Item(id: "item-1", name: "Item 1")
        var body: some View {
            CustomPicker(items: [Item(id: "item-1", name: "Item 1"), Item(id: "item-2", name: "Item 2")], selection: $selection) { item in
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                    Text("\(item.name)")
                }
                .padding()
            }
        }
    }
    
    static var previews: some View {
        Container()
    }
}
```

[image: Preview]

Comment: can it be more like system animation with? !